# Laravel EB Bootstrap and Storage directories

Tags: amazon-elastic-beanstalk, laravel-8

I am struggling with getting the config script on EB to set up the bootstrap and storage directories in my Laravel application with the correct permissions.

It seems that when I deploy the directories are not being set with the correct permissions and therefore composer has a hard time executing.

Can someone provide the code for making a config file to set the permissions on these directories correctly? Thanks!

Comment: ELB is elastic load balancer, not Elastic beanstalk.

Comment: Thanks, noted. I got it working anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it working since it actually was not the directories causing the error. I found that it was a class which did not want to load.